# Flow Loop Element not showing Sobject Variable

Tags: visual-workflow, loop

I'm working on a flow where i do a fast lookup to the contact object and store the ids found in a sobject variable but this variable is not showing up as an option for selection when a i add a loop element.  any ideas why this would be?

Thanks,
JG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an SObject Collection Variable. Unlike an SObject Variable, collections can hold multiple records. This is noted in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_elements_fast_lookup.htm):

> Make sure that your filter criteria sufficiently narrows the search. If you use an **sObject variable** to store the results, the Fast Lookup element returns **only the first record** from the filtered results. *(Emphasis added)*